# How to pass parameters to a batch file using c#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a console file, which takes 6 arguments

[image]

To run this exe, I create one batch file,

[image]

Now, I need to send this parameter to the batch file from my one Windows application. This is the code:

```
         string consolepath = @"E:\SqlBackup_Programs\console-backup\Backup_Console_App";
            string Pc = "VARUN-PC";
            string database = "Smart_Tracker";
            string UserName = "sa";
            string Password = "admin@12";
            string bacPath = @"D:\TEST";

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BATCH_FULLBACKUP"].ToString().Trim();
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(consolepath,Pc,database,UserName,Password,"F",bacPath);
            //set the rest of the process settings
            proc.Start();
```

But its not working. I tried to change my Batch file like,

@echo off
 %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7

@echo off

but that didn't work either.

Error Image:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Arguments` should be `seperated` by `space`.

**Method 1:**

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments =consolepath+" "+Pc+" "+database+" "+UserName+" "+Password+" "+"F"+" "+bacPath;
```

**Method 2:** using `String.Format()`

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments =String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}",consolepath,Pc,database,UserName,Password,"F",bacPath);
```

**Solution 2:**  you should not hardcode the parameter values in batch file

Try This: change the Batch file as below

```
%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7
```

Comment: When I use this above both method my batch file run exe,
according to its own value, i mean it did not take values from this arguments,
so, is there any change require in batch file ???

currently my batch file is same as showing upper image,
I give different last arguments in code "E:\"  but still its follow batch file path.

Comment: @VARUNNAYAK: actually it works ,ok let me check it .

Comment: @VARUNNAYAK : did you check it? it is working for me.

Comment: No its not,
See, last argument its where to save this backup file,
I give "D:\Test" in batch file,
but in code i give it "E:\",
And its store backup in "D:\TEST",
Its simply run batch file didnt pass arguments

Comment: I also add that screen shot in last image.. Check it

Comment: @VARUNNAYAK: it might be overriding your arguments , could you please show the batch script

Comment: I already shown it in upper image,
its..


"E:\SqlBackup_Programs\console-backup\Backup_Console_App" VARUN-PC Smart_Tracker  sa admin@12 F "D:\TEST"

Comment: @VARUNNAYAK: you have hardcoded the values in batch file so how can you expect that those arguments(passed from C# program) whould be taken by your batch file.let me edit my answer

Comment: @VARUNNAYAK: check my edited answer with `Solution 2`

Comment: No its still not working , i add Comparison Error in my question, check that image,
In first image there shows my batch file which runs perfectly n in 2nd image shows when i change batch file according to u

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, My console application does not allow to save backup on "E:" path

Comment: +1 @SudhakarTillapudi Thank you friend you have helped me too

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi i have a one doubt..My batch was located in server..how can i call that batch From my Asp.net applicaton.Please reply me

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a format for your String.Format call.

`proc.StartInfo.Arguments` should be more like

```
String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}",  consolepath,Pc,database,UserName,Password,"F",bacPath);
```

However, keep in mind that your arguments could contain whitespaces. I would do this.

```
var args = new string[] { consolepath,Pc,database,UserName,Password,"F",bacPath };
var startupInfo = String.Join(" ", args.Select(x => "\"" + x + "\""));
```

Comment: `{7}` is not required as there are only 7 arguments.